# Comparing objects of class which has implemented comparable

Tags: java, compare

I'm learning binary search tree and trying to implement it in Java.

```
    public class BinarySearchTree<T>
    {
        private class Node
        {
            public T data;
            public Node left;
            public Node right;
        }

        //some code goes here

        public void insert(T data)
        {
            //make a new node and add data to that node
            //call to recursive function
        }
        private Node ins(Node root,Node toBeInserted)
        {
            if(root==null) { root = tobeInserted; return root; }

            //problem is here...
            else if(toBeInserted.data<=root.data)// <----How to do this ?????
                root = ins(root.left,toBeInserted);
            else
                root = ins(root.right,toBeInserted);
            return root;
        }
        //some more code
    }
```

Problem is how to compare the objects of class T??
If I had implemented comparable in some class T, then how to compare data stored in left and right node???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `T` always implements `Comparable`, you can add the appropriate bound to its definition:

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>> { ... }
```

then you can use `compareTo()`:

```
toBeInserted.data.compareTo(root.data) <= 0
```

Comment: if T has implemented many interfaces and in some other class like above requires at least two functions from different interface then??

Comment: Is it SomeClass<T extends InterFace1,InterFace2> ?? which does not seems to be possible

Comment: `T extends InterFace1 & InterFace2`

Answer (score 0):

Make the class definition as

```
public class BinarySearchTree<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

and then for insertion

Try this out

```
  /**
  * This method inserts new node in tree
  * @param value
  */
 public void insert(T value){
  if(isEmpty())
   root = new Node(value);  //root node added
  else
   insert(root, value);  //if not empty then insert based on root
 }

 /**
  * Recursive method is called internally to insert nodes at proper 
    places depending on their vakues.
  * @param node
  * @param value
  */
 private void insert(Node node, T value){
  if(value.compareTo(node.value) < 0){  //if new value less than parent node
   if(node.left == null)  //if left null then add
    node.left = new Node(value);
   else
    insert(node.left,value);  //if left not null then recursive call
  }
  else if(value.compareTo(node.value) >= 0){  //if new value same or greater than parent node
   if(node.right == null)  //if right null then add
    node.right = new Node(value);
   else
    insert(node.right,value);  //if right not null then recursive call
  }
 }
```

Visit the link [here](http://javaingrab.blogspot.com/2014/06/implementation-of-generic-binary-search.html) for the complete source code.